# re-install xcode12.2 commandline tools on Monterey

Tags: xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

I know you can use xcode-select to switch the version of XCode you are using (both 13.2 and 12.2 in my case), however, how do I get back to the 12.2 version of commandline tools.  I've downloaded the dmg, however, Monterey won't let me install it (too new of an OS).

Comment: You have said it: "too new of an OS".

Comment: @matt thanks.  I know you can launch xcode12 via the commandline (as we need it for 2 more months until we update our project to use xcode13), just didn't now if there was a way to go back to the old command line tools.

Comment: Well, I think you proved there isn't. — I've played that game with the command line too! It's a little creaky but it does work. :)))

Comment: Yeah we've been using it while we await some open source that is not working with XCode13 but I made the mistake if updating the commandline tools and now I'm stuck :(

Comment: But if you have Xcode isn't it all inside there already? What do you need the tools for?

Comment: we use command line build tools of Carthage and Fastlane

Comment: But they will see the build tools sitting right there in your copy of Xcode if you point to it with `xcode-select`. We seem to be going around in circles. The command line tools are for people who do _not_ have Xcode.

Comment: @matt, thanks but I think I may not have explained my situation enough.  I'm on Monterey and have XCode 12.5 installed along with the build tools.  We use XCode to develop in and then use FastLane to do our builds (hence we need commandline tools).  Now that I've installed 13.2 it updated the build tools to 13.2 as well so that we can update and use 13.2.  We have issue that requires us to modify our current build which was built on 12.5.  I  used to be able to use xcode-select and it would swap between the 2 versions, however how it does not.  Even if I point to the 12.2 version

Comment: If you have a project built with Xcode 12.5 and you want to work with it some more, just whip out another computer that hasn't been updated to Monterey. Make sure you do not open that project with Xcode 13, as it may become incompatible with Xcode 12. — However I do not understand why you would build with Xcode 12, as you can never submit that build to the App Store.

Comment: @matt Thanks .. yep our build server is still Xcode12.  You can still submit with that until Feb.  Just don't have a second mac to do local stuff.  We are going to bite the bullet and just get our 3rd party open source libraries running on xcode13.

Comment: "Just don't have a second mac to do local stuff" Ok, then install a virtual machine running an earlier OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion, it appears there is no way to do this.  We will just get our code base all up to run on Xcode13